# iOS Web App won't play delayed audio but directly playing works. Only on iOS devices running as web app

Tags: ios, flutter, web

I'm encountering this very odd behavior on my Flutter Web app when running on iOS device (simulator or real device), where audio is not being played when playing it delayed.

In the following code you can see I'm playing a sound effect after delaying it by a few seconds with `Future.delayed`. This is to implement a countdown timer that plays a tick sound in the last three seconds.

This works everywhere except as a web app when running on iOS devices, it works even as an iOS app. You can test it on an iOS simulator, just start the app with `flutter run -d web-server`, then open the localhost in the safari app on the simulator. You will see that no sound is being played.

I have tried different audio packages, they all have the same behavior. It works when I remove the initial `await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7));` but I really need the delay to work.

Any kind of help or explanation for this behavior is very appreciated.

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tts/flutter_tts.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart' as justAudio;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final player = AudioPlayer();
  AssetSource tick5 = AssetSource("sounds/tick5.mp3");


  void playAudio() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7));
    await player.play(tick5, volume: 1);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    await player.play(tick5, volume: 1);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    await player.play(tick5, volume: 1);
  }

  void playAudioJust() async {
    justAudio.AudioPlayer player = justAudio.AudioPlayer();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7));
    player.setAsset("sounds/tick5.mp3");
    player.play();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    player.setAsset("sounds/tick5.mp3");
    player.play();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    player.setAsset("sounds/tick5.mp3");
    player.play();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextButton(onPressed: playAudio, child: Text("Audioplayers")),
          TextButton(onPressed: playAudioJust, child: Text("JustAudio")),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My `pubspec.yaml`

```
name: empty_flutter_project
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  audioplayers:
  just_audio:

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/sounds/
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS, both with Chrome and Safari don't allow sounds unless initiated by a user action.  The delay kills the sound.

You need to start the sound on a user action, then create a listener, and pause as soon as it starts.  Then you can resume the sound later.  It's asynchronous, so you need the listener.

```
  player.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((PlayerState s) => {
    //check for state playing, pause if so.
  });
```

when time expires: resume.